# How to create project in firebase programmatically

Tags: firebase

I need to automate the process of registering projects in firebase and adding android and ios apps to the projects (and getting their their server-key and sender-id). Is there a way to do that progrommatically, using API or CLI?

Comment: Create projects is possible through the API, but adding apps is not (afaik).

Comment: Can you please share the link?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest/ (also the first link in the top answer to the first question I linked)